# Make an array using declared variables and bubble sort?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, bubble-sort

I have a code below that reads data from a text file and prints it out in tabular form. One thing I need to do is make an array that calculates the wage. The wage is calculated using an "if else" statement since it has to factor in for overtime. The table needs to include the wage as well and this would be easy but I need to perform a bubble sort which will organize the data in order from highest wage to lowest wage. At the bottom of the table the total of all the wages needs to be displayed.

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <cmath>

 using namespace std;


 int main()
 {
 ifstream myFile("Assignment4.txt");
 if (!myFile.is_open())
 {
    cout << "File Failed to Open!" << endl;
    return 0;
 }

 string firstname, lastname;
 int id, hours;
 double rate, wage;

 string myString;
 string line;
 cout << "First Name |" << " Last Name |" << " Employee ID |" << " Hourly Rate($) |" << " Hours |" << 
 " Wage($)" <<endl;
 while (getline(myFile, line))
 {
    stringstream ss(line);
    getline(ss, firstname, ':');
    getline(ss, lastname, ':');
    getline(ss, myString, ':');
    rate = stoi(myString);
    getline(ss, myString, ':');
    id = stoi(myString);
    getline(ss, myString, '\n');
    hours = stoi(myString);
 }
 myFile.close();

 int array;
 const int NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES = 100;
 array = new int[capacity];

 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (hours <= 40)
        wage = rate * hours;
    else
        wage = rate * 40 + ((hours - 40) * rate * 1.5);

    cout << setw(10) << firstname << " |" << 
    setw(10)
        << lastname << " |" << setw(12)
        << id << " |" << setw(15)
        << rate << " |" << setw(6)
    << hours << " | " << wage << endl;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Above is the code I am trying to get to work with my failed attempt at setting up an array right before the wage logic. Below is the text file I am reading from.

Mike:Jones:567:25.75:67

Sue:Smith:45:30.25:82

Ann:Barber:2:15.45:39

Billy:Simpson:1234:10.15:65

Barabara:Stone:75:45.33:22

Alan:Colllins:17:12.75:73

Cindy:Davis:210:13.67:45

Eilein:Ferguson:62:53.36:17

Gordon:Howard:981:9.89:31

Bob:Jones:295:14.73:43

(there is no white space between the lines added for separation)
The code NEEDS to use a system of arrays as well as a bubble sort. The code is also intended to hold a maximum number of entries of 100 even though the text file only lists 10. My main questions are: how do I set up the wage function as an array? how do I perform a bubble sort on this array from highest to lowest wages?  And how do I sum the total of the wages?

Comment: `array = new int[capacity];` isn't going to work with `int array` needs to be `int* array`. And regardless I'd use `std::vector` anyway if you are allowed to.

Comment: Don't write your own sort.  Use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: Any idea how i can include a sort for this scenario?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).